# MarkLogic how to replace specify attribute in the node

Tags: marklogic

How to replace attribute num = "3" to num = "000"
example:

```
 <meta:Descriptors xmlns:sup="http://next.com/record" xmlns:meta="http://next.com/record/meta">
    <meta:Descriptor Num="1">test 1</meta:Descriptor>
    <meta:Descriptor Num="2">test 2</meta:Descriptor>
    <meta:Descriptor Num="3">test 3</meta:Descriptor>
    <meta:Descriptor Num="4">test 4</meta:Descriptor>
 </meta:Descriptors>
```

I try xdmp:node-replace(). However all the @Num change to "000".  How can I only want change attribute Num="3" to Num="000".

```
 xdmp:node-replace(fn:doc("test.xml")/data:record//meta:Descriptor/@Num,attribute {"Num"} {"000"})
```

the result:

```
<meta:Descriptors xmlns:sup="http://next.com/record" xmlns:meta="http://next.com/record/meta">
    <meta:Descriptor Num="000">test 1</meta:Descriptor>
    <meta:Descriptor Num="000">test 2</meta:Descriptor>
    <meta:Descriptor Num="000">test 3</meta:Descriptor>
    <meta:Descriptor Num="000">test 4</meta:Descriptor>
 </meta:Descriptors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modifying the XPath to select the specific attribute that should change, as in:

```
fn:doc("test.xml")//meta:Descriptor/@Num[string(.) eq "3"]
```

Hoping that helps,